# "Cannot invoke 'CGPointMake' with an argument list of type '((), CGFloat)'" received in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I got this error message for `CGPointMake()`

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/RevivalxSwiftSlider/RevivalxSwiftSlider/RangeSlider.swift:66:28: Cannot invoke 'CGPointMake' with an argument list of type '((), CGFloat)'

My code

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    _minThumb.center = CGPointMake(self.xForValue(selectedMinimumValue), self.center.y);

}

func xForValue(value: Float){
        return (self.frame.size.width-(_padding*2))*((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue))+_padding;
    }
```

`selectedMinimumValue` is a float.

Comment: Add code for `xForValue` please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast it CGFloat

```
_minThumb.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(self.xForValue(selectedMinimumValue)), self.center.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your **xForValue** method has return value, can you try to cast **Float(self.xForValue(selectedMinimumValue))** ?

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 2):

CGPoint take a CGFloat, not a Float, you should cast it before using

```
CGFloat(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things: 
One, Your xForValue function hasn't declared a return type. It should be:

```
func xForValue(value: Float) -> Float {
    return (self.frame.size.width-(_padding*2))*((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue))+_padding;
}
```

Two, as said in other responses, `CGPointMake` takes a CGFloat, so you'll need to either have xForValue return a CGFloat, or cast it, as other answers have said.